# INNER JOIN between 2 $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_ tables using MDXQuery

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, mdx-query

I'm doing some queries in a SSAS model using SSMS and MDXQuery . I'm able to run a single select on any table as below:

```
SELECT[TableID], [Name] FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS
```

[image]

```
SELECT [ID], [Name] FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_TABLES
```

[image]

The first select gives me the partitionNames assign to each table and the table ID, now I want to know what is the table name behind that TableID but I've tried a JOIN between both tables but I'm getting an error

```
SELECT[TableID], [Name] FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS a
```

JOIN $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_TABLES b
on a.TableId = b.ID

[image]

I am more a SQL developer so I though the JOIN might work but is not , how can I join these 2 tables to get all needed columns?

Comment: You could pull them into a Tabular Model and join them in Power Query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do joins via SQL with Dynamic Management View tables. The SQL used for DMVs is a subset of T-SQL. The normal approach is to load the data into tables and then do the joins. I do this all the time in Power Query from Excel and Power BI Desktop.

Here are my sources:

https://isura777.blogspot.com/2016/03/dynamic-management-views-for-ssas.html

> SQL statements can be used to query the row sets, but have following
> limitation in SQL 2008 version.
>
> - SELECT DISTINCT does not return DISTINCT values
> - ORDER BY clause accepts just one field to order by. Only one order expression is allowed for TOP Expression at line 1, column 1?
> - COUNT, SUM does not work
> - ORDER BY  does not ORDER, but no error
> - JOINS appear not to work
> - LIKE does not work
> - IN doesn't work, but [col] = '1' OR [col] = '2' does work
> - String functions like LEFT do not work

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh230820(v=sql.110)

> Although DMV query syntax is based on a SQL SELECT statement, it does not support the full syntax of a SELECT statement.  Notably, JOIN, GROUP BY, LIKE, CAST, and CONVERT are not supported.